# Why would a viewlets.xml file not contain same viewlets seen in @@manage-viewlets for its theme?

Tags: xml, export, plone, viewlets

When exporting viewlets.xml file from portal_setup for both Plone 3.3.5 and Plone4 sites and compare it to the site's @@manage-viewlets page, I see incongruities.

For example, some viewlets appear in the wrong Viewlet Manager or not at all. Is this common or what could be done differently for improved results?

Typically this is for sites without themes where the theme is being created from a stand-alone site.

thanks!

Comment: Your question can't really be answered effectively, because you assume improving the results makes sense; I'm not sure it does though (i.e. in order for it to make sense, it should be something universally desirable, or almost so). In any event, sounds like it could be a bug so please file a detailed bug report at http://dev.plone.org/plone/report i.e. how to reproduce, why you want to see congruent results, etc.

Comment: @aclark Surely, having @@manage-viewlets actually match the genuine GS configuration can only be a Good Thing (tm).  I'm not sure it isn't really matching - but I confess I've often felt that @@manage-viewlets is not showing reality.

Comment: @@manage-viewlets is generally not supported… my understanding is it was added at the last minute prior to release of 3.0 and is currently awaiting either improvement or deprecation.

Comment: @aclark I had not checked in for a while; sincere apologies. A solution presented itself which may be the reason for the question. These sites were setup in 3.3.5 then I wanted to make them into Plone 4 site Themes. The issue was that the skin (3.3.5) was based on "Plone Default" whereas the Plone4 skin was based on "Plone Classic Theme". There was a basic disagreement on viewlets viewed in @@manage-viewlets and the corresponding viewlets.xml file. And @auspex was correct that these do not match up always; I misunderstood that. Thanks for commenting on the question.

Comment: I'd be happy to upvote the given infos of the comments, if they are pasted into an answer :)